# Free audio player API

Tags: c#, api, dll, audio

I need to add pretty basic audio player functionality to a client application I'm writing (I think it will be WPF based).

Can anyone please recommend a good audio player library with basic functionality (Playback control, Basic EQ and that's it) and a .NET API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/):

> NAudio is an open source .NET audio
>   and MIDI library, containing dozens of
>   useful audio related classes intended
>   to speed development of audio related
>   utilities in .NET. It has been in
>   development since 2001 and has grown
>   to include a wide variety of features.

There's a few sample apps that come with the library, one of which is a WPF application, so you can certainly use it there.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) provides audio playback for WPF applications although I am not sure if it has any EQ support.

Comment: I think NAudio is not a viable API (Specially due to the resource leaks and inconsistency). Of course this is my opinion. I would prefer use Net Audio or Bass Audio Library instead.